# Top N Number of trending Post

Tags: mongodb

I have a dataset of 100. Out of this, I have to show top 10 Post. My dataset looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e581775549510d8e5ee07"),
    "post" : "1",
    "trendingvalue" :50,
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e581775549510d8e5ee08"),
    "post" : "2",
    "trendingvalue" :40,
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e581775549510d8e5ee09"),
    "post" : "3",
    "trendingvalue" :21,
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2e581775549510d8e5ee01"),
    "post" : "4",
    "trendingvalue" :45,
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2017-12-11T10:04:07.526Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},and so on upto 100.
```

Now, How can I achieve this? I am trying to Implement the Query But not get the desired result.

```
{"_id" :5a2e581775549510d8e5ee07, "value": 50},
{"_id" :5a2e581775549510d8e5ee01, "value": 45},
{"_id" :5a2e581775549510d8e5ee08, "value": 40},
{"_id" :5a2e581775549510d8e5ee09, "value": 21}
```

My query is like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$trendingvalue"},
    //{$sort: {"trendingdelta": -1}},
    {$group: {"_id": "$_id", "value": "$trendingdelta"}},
    //{$project: {"trendingdelta": "$trendingdelta"}}
    ], function(error, data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Any Help is appreciate

Comment: Try `db.collection_name.find().sort( { trendingvalue: -1} ).limit( 10 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this , slightly modified according to your question :-

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$trendingvalue"},
    {$project: { trendingvalue: 1 }},
    {$sort: {trendingvalue: -1}},
    { $limit : 10 }
    ]);
```